# regex expression to validate input pattern (ZHA123456) Javascript only

Tags: javascript, regex, input

I am doing my college assignment of pure javascript I am facing problem doing the following task

**A valid Zedland Health Authority Number has been entered. Zedland Health
Authority numbers are in the form of a six-digit integer prefixed with the letters
ZHA (e.g. ZHA346783).**

I know how to validate input value I just need a regex which validates if first three letters are **ZHA** and next values should be 6 digits long numeric only.

Comment: Try this /ZHA\d{6}/g

Comment: Are they not giving out books or course material over there? Please attempt the solution yourself. We'll be happy to help when you get stuck with actual coding.

Comment: You should check out https://regexone.com/. It's an awesome place to learn the basics of regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^ZHA\d{6}
```

This asserts that the beginning of the string will contain ZHA. The next 6 characters are numeric so you can use `\d{6}`